# A problem of assigning functions to the “best” axes

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, continuity

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $N\equiv\{1,\ldots,n\}$. If $j\in N$ and $x_j$ is a real number, let $(x_j|\mathbf 0_{-j})$ denote the vector in $\mathbb R^n$ whose $j$th coordinate is $x_j$ and all other coordinates are $0$.

For each $i\in N$, suppose that $f^i:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a function such that

- $f^i$ is continuous;
- $f^i$ is strictly increasing in each coordinate; in particular, $f^i(x_j|\mathbf 0_{-j})>f^i(y_j|\mathbf 0_{-j})$ for each $j\in N$ whenever $x_j>y_j$; and
- $f^1(\mathbf 0)=\cdots=f^n(\mathbf 0)=0$.

> **Conjecture:** Fix any $\varepsilon>0$. There exist $\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n$ and a permutation $\pi:N\to N$ of the indices such that
>
> - $0<\delta_j<\varepsilon$ for each $j\in N$; and
> - $f^{\pi(i)}(\delta_i|\mathbf 0_{-i})\geq f^{\pi(i)}(\delta_j|\mathbf 0_{-j})$ for all $i,j\in N$.

The intuition is as follows. The functions take the same value at the origin. In addition, attention is restricted to evaluating the functions only along the $n$ axes (where at most one coordinate is non-zero).

> Is it possible to construct a small positive perturbation around the origin such that each of the $n$ functions can be matched to one of the $n$ axes in such a way that
>
> (i) each function takes the highest value on the very axis to which it is matched; and
>
> (ii) no two functions are matched to the same axis?

The case $n=2$ is not very difficult and the intermediate-value theorem comes in handy. I put considerable effort into trying to construct a counterexample for $n=3$ in vain, which has led me to suspect that the conjecture is in fact true also in higher dimensions. But a proof has eluded me, too.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't care about the values of $f^i$ off the axes, so really you have $n^2$ functions $f_j^i$, arranged in a matrix. You pick a number $\delta_j$ for each column and plug it into those functions. Then you look for the top values in each row, hoping this forms a permutation matrix. That is, your setup gives a function $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^n \to M_{\geq 0}^{n \times n}$, and you're hoping that it hits a certain subset of $M_{n \times n}$. This may have some algebraic topology argument, e.g. exclude the target subset from the codomain and make a topological argument that the map can't exist.

Comment: E.g. for $n=2$ excluding the target subset splits the codomain in two, but the domain is connected and the edge cases hit both connected components. There may be some similar argument in higher dimensions. E.g. some "boundary" of the domain maps topologically nontrivially into the codomain with the target set removed, but the full domain is simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** The conjecture turns out to be true for $n=3$, but the proof I came up with is “ugly” and inelegant (see below). Moreover, since the proof is non-inductive (it essentially resorts to brute force), it also leaves me none the wiser about how to approach the case $n\geq 4$. As a result, this answer still leaves the general question open. Please, do contribute and claim the bounty. :-)

---

Suppose that $n=3$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$. Take three arbitrary numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ from the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$. Let me focus on the function $f^1$ first. Without loss of generality (rearrange the axis indices if necessary), assume that $$f^1(x_1,0,0)\geq f^1(0,x_2,0)\geq f^1(0,0,x_3).$$ By slightly increasing $x_1$ and decreasing $x_3$ if necessary, there is no loss in assuming that the inequalities above are strict: $$f^1(x_1,0,0)> f^1(0,x_2,0)>f^1(0,0,x_3)>0,$$ where the very last inequality follows from strict monotonicity and the fact that $f^1(0,0,0)=0$. Let $x_3^*\equiv x_3$. By the intermediate-value theorem, there exist $x_1^*\in(0,x_1)$ and $x_2^*\in(0,x_2)$ such that $$f^1(x_1^*,0,0)=f^1(0,x_2^*,0)=f^1(0,0,x_3^*).\tag{1}$$ This “tie” makes it possible to have $f^1$ matched to any one of the three axes in the desired way.

To decide which axes $f^2$ and $f^3$ should be matched to, consider two cases.

**Case 1:** The three points $(x_1^*,0,0)$, $(0,x_2^*,0)$, and $(0,0,x_3^*)$ are such that both $f^2$ and $f^3$ are uniquely maximized on the same axis $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. Without loss, suppose that $i=1$. This means that
\begin{align*}
f^2(x_1^*,0,0)&>\max\left\{f^2(0,x_2^*,0),f^2(0,0,x_3^*)\right\}\tag{2},\\
f^3(x_1^*,0,0)&>\max\left\{f^3(0,x_2^*,0),f^3(0,0,x_3^*)\right\}\tag{3}.
\end{align*}
Since

(i) $f^2(0,x_2^*,0)$, $f^2(0,0,x_3^*)$, $f^3(0,x_2^*,0)$, and $f^3(0,0,x_3^*)$ are all positive; and

(ii) $f^2(0,0,0)=f^3(0,0,0)=0$,

the intermediate-value theorem makes it possible to decrease $x_1^*$ to some positive value $x_1^{**}\in(0,x_1^*)$ such that (at least) one of the two inequalities (2)–(3) becomes an equality, and the other one remains a (weak) inequality. Without loss once again, assume that
\begin{align*}
f^2(x_1^{**},0,0)&=\max\left\{f^2(0,x_2^*,0),f^2(0,0,x_3^*)\right\}\tag{4},\\
f^3(x_1^{**},0,0)&\geq\max\left\{f^3(0,x_2^*,0),f^3(0,0,x_3^*)\right\}\tag{5}.
\end{align*}
Consider the three points $(x_1^{**},0,0)$, $(0,x_2^*,0)$, and $(0,0,x_3^*)$. The inequality (5) implies that $f^3$ can be assigned to the first axis. The equality (4) implies that $f^2$ can be assigned to either the second or the third axis, depending on the relative magnitudes of $f^2(0,x_2^*,0)$ and $f^3(0,0,x_3^*)$. Finally, the equality (1) and the fact that $x_1^{**}<x_1^*$ imply that $$f^1(x_1^{**},0,0)<f^1(0,x_2^*,0)=f^1(0,0,x_3^*).$$ Therefore, $f^1$ can be assigned to either the second or the third axis, depending on which one has not already been taken by $f^2$.

**Case 2:** The functions $f^2$ and $f^3$ can be (not necessarily strictly and not necessarily in a unique way) maximized at two different axes when the three points are $(x_1^*,0,0)$, $(0,x_2^*,0)$, and $(0,0,x_3^*)$. Let each of those two functions take its “favorite” axis. By the equality (1), $f^1$ can take the third remaining axis.